# Why my jest tests are not using my mock Class? How to fix it?

Tags: typescript, testing, mocking, ts-jest, launchdarkly

Why my tests are not using the mock functions? The tests are failing because they are calling the actual `initClient` function inside the `LaunchDarklyClient`

`launchDarkly.ts`

```
export class LaunchDarklyClient {
  client: LDClient;

  constructor() {}

  async initClient(ldKeySecretName: string) {
    console.log('ldKeySecretName is: ', ldKeySecretName);
    const sdkKeyResponse = await getSecret({
      SecretId: ldKeySecretName,
    });

    const sdkKey = sdkKeyResponse.SecretString;
    try {
      console.log('Initializing LaunchDarkly');
      const client = ld.init(sdkKey);

      this.client = client;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error initializing LaunchDarkly: ', err);
    }
  }

  async getFeatureFlag(key: string): Promise<any> {
    console.log('Fetching feature flag: ', key);
    try {
      const ldContext = {
        key: 'anonymous',
      };
      const result = await this.client.variation(key, ldContext, false);

      return result;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Couldnt get feature flag from LaunchDarkly: ', err);
      return null;
    }
  }
}

export const getFeatureFlags = async (
  ldKey: string,
  flagNames: string[],
): Promise<iFlags> => {
  const ldClient = new LaunchDarklyClient();
  const flags: iFlags = {};

  try {
    await ldClient.initClient(ldKey);
    await ldClient.client.waitForInitialization();

    for (const flagName of flagNames) {
      const flagValue = await ldClient.getFeatureFlag(flagName);
      flags[flagName] = flagValue;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('LaunchDarkly client did not initialize: ', err);
    flagNames.forEach((flagName) => (flags[flagName] = null));
  }

  console.log('returning feature flags: ', flags);
  return flags;
};
```

`launchDarkly.spec.ts`

```
import { getFeatureFlags, LaunchDarklyClient } from './launchDarkly';

jest.mock('./launchDarkly', () => {
    return {
        ...jest.requireActual('./launchDarkly'),
        LaunchDarklyClient:jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
              initClient: jest.fn(),
              client: {
                waitForInitialization: jest.fn(),
              },
              getFeatureFlag: jest.fn(),
            };
        })
    }
});

describe('getFeatureFlags', () => {
  const ldKey = 'test-ld-key';
  const flagNames = ['flag1', 'flag2'];
  let ldClient;

  beforeEach(() => {
    ldClient = new LaunchDarklyClient();
  });

  it('should return flags when LaunchDarkly client initializes successfully', async () => {
    ldClient.initClient.mockResolvedValue(undefined);
    ldClient.client.waitForInitialization.mockResolvedValue(undefined);
    ldClient.getFeatureFlag.mockImplementation(flagName => Promise.resolve(flagName + '-value'));

    const flags = await getFeatureFlags(ldKey, flagNames);

    expect(ldClient.initClient).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ldKey);
    expect(ldClient.client.waitForInitialization).toHaveBeenCalled();
    flagNames.forEach(flagName => {
      expect(ldClient.getFeatureFlag).toHaveBeenCalledWith(flagName);
      expect(flags[flagName]).toEqual(flagName + '-value');
    });
  });

  it('should return null for all flags when LaunchDarkly client initialization fails', async () => {
    ldClient.initClient.mockRejectedValue(new Error('Initialization failed'));

    const flags = await getFeatureFlags(ldKey, flagNames);

    expect(ldClient.initClient).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ldKey);
    expect(ldClient.client.waitForInitialization).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    flagNames.forEach(flagName => {
      expect(flags[flagName]).toBeNull();
    });
  });
});
```